# DataFlow ProcessContext output exception ClosedChannelException

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm parsing XML from stream, and dispatching POJO to ProcessContext.output.
It's throwing following ClosedChannelException. 
Any idea what's going on?

```
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(DoFnRunner.java:193)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.processElement(DoFnRunner.java:171)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase.processElement(ParDoFnBase.java:193)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ParDoFnBase$1.output(ParDoFnBase.java:157)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:329)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:483)
    at com.myproj.dataflow.MyDocDispatcher.onMyDoc(MyDocDispatcher.java:24)
```

Comment: please format question with exception using code formatting

Comment: Is this exception due to error in next step of dataflow? I see element is being passed to the next dataflow transform step, and being processed successfully.

Comment: This exception means that you closed the channel and then continued to use it.

Comment: Could you share more details about how your DoFn is processing XML? Naively, it seems possible that the POJO that is being output is actually being lazily parsed when the next DoFn tries to interact with the POJO, rather than eagerly before being output.

Answer (score 1):

One likely cause of this is that your `DoFn` that does the XML processing to produce a POJO actually lazily produces the POJO. When you pass that POJO to `ProcessContext#output()` it may be directly passed to other `DoFn`s later in the pipeline, based on the optimizer.

In this case, if the downstream `DoFn` interacting with the POJO has some side-effects on the POJO that was received, it violates the [immutability requirements](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/DoFn#processElement-com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.DoFn.ProcessContext-), since interacting with the POJO received from the `ProcessContext#element()` modifies it.

If this is the problem, the easiest fix is cloning the POJO before passing it to `output()`.